# Apache mod_md: procedure for handling multiple VirtualHosts?

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a working setup for multiple virtual hosts on the same server, but there's a problem: all the server's SSL certificates are unnecessarily renewed, and moved, whenever a vhost is added.

In this setup, each vhost has a separate `.conf` file, and the host is individually enabled with `a2ensite`.

For 2 sites, this looks like:

```
MDomain foo.com
MDStoreDir /var/apache-md/foo.com
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www1
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and:

```
MDomain bar.com
MDStoreDir /var/apache-md/bar.com
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName bar.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www2
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enable `foo.com` and reload Apache, I get a certificate in `/var/apache-md/foo.com/domains/foo.com/pubcert.pem`. So far, so good. But when I later enable `bar.com`, I now get *2* new sets of certificates, and end up with:

1. `/var/apache-md/foo.com/domains/foo.com/pubcert.pem`
2. `/var/apache-md/bar.com/domains/foo.com/pubcert.pem`
3. `/var/apache-md/bar.com/domains/bar.com/pubcert.pem`

If I run

```
$ openssl s_client -connect foo.com:443 -prexit
```

I find that Apache is now serving certificate 2 for `foo.com`, not certificate 1. This is obviously not a good way to do this: it seems that every time I add a vhost all the certificates get renewed and are all stored in the location for the last host added.

I have also tried setting `MDStoreDir` to the same location (`/var/apache-md`) for all hosts, but I couldn't get this to work.  `mod_md` seems to check whether this directory exists. If it already exists, it won't get a new certificate. Any ideas on how to best do this?

No idea which version of `mod_md` I'm using; there doesn't seem to be a way to find out. It's fairly recent (Apache 2.4.52 on Ubunut 22.04).

Comment: The module is still experimental and should not be used in production. Stick with certbot.

Answer (score 0):

MDStoreDir is a server context setting.  meaning it is a global setting that  exists once per apache.conf.  when you attempt to set it uniquely for the second vhost it overrides the previous declaration.